# Adding maxlenght to textbox

Tags: jquery

Some value are returned to ajax from C#. I need to bind those values to GridView. Everything works ok but only difference is this value: `$("span", row).eq(4).attr("maxlength",this.MaxNoPlaces);` needs to be bind to `MaxLength` property of textbox instead of value.

I also tried input instead of span and attr `maxlength` but it is not working.

```
$(document).on('click', ".myBtn", function() {

  header = $(this).closest('tr').find('.ObjekatID').text()
  console.log(header);


  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Administration.aspx/GetRequest",
    data: JSON.stringify({
      'header2': header2
    }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      var row = $("[id*=grdDemo] tr:last-child").clone(true);
      $("[id*=grdDemo] tr").not($("[id*=grdDemo] tr:first-child")).remove();
      //  alert($("[id*=grdDemo]").html());
      var count = 1;
      $.each(data.d, function() {
        $("span", row).eq(0).html(this.ObjectID);
        $("span", row).eq(1).html(this.ObjectName);
        $("span", row).eq(2).html(this.ObjectValue);
        $("span", row).eq(3).html(this.ObjectTypeID);

        $("span", row).eq(4).attr("maxlength", this.MaxNoPlaces);

        $("[id*=grdDemo] tbody").append(row);
        console.log(row);
        if (count == 1 || (count % 2 != 0)) {
          $(row).css("background-color", "rgb(193, 212, 248)");
        } else {
          $(row).css("background-color", "white");
        }
        count = count + 1;
        row = $("[id*=grdDemo] tr:last-child").clone(true);

      });


    },
    error: function() {
      console.log("Not Saved!");
    }

  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try to hide this using overflow : hidden.

Below is on example,

```
 .span100p {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
   }

<span class="span100p ">Hello world this is a long sentence</span>
```

Please reply if you need anything...

Comment: I don't need to hide anything, just to bind value to maxlenght propery of textbox.

Comment: Actually, its setting the max length property. But you are binding value in background, so it will take the value as it is. You cant add more than limited number through UI. Its an expected behaviour only.

If you want, u can shrink that data as per the text box value.

Comment: When I enter html there is no maxlenght atribute.

Comment: Can you check the maxlength property in Inspect Element. It should be updated in the span tag.

Can you provide me the Html content.

Comment: MaxLenght is updated in the element after in the gird span(5), this element is not shown in the code example. That because row(4) is a textbox, all other elements are label :/